# Display Resources Root as folders not packages in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to display the folders in the resources root as folders and not as packages? I can remove the 'marking' of the folder but this does not sounds like a straight way of doing it...

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

The folders inside source/resource roots are actual packages, so it is by design that IDE always treats them a such. What is the real issue with displaying the folders as packages? Note that there are different [viewing modes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#title_bar_context_menu) in Project tool window you can use  (e.g. **Flatten Packages**).